# Is there SQL Logic to reduce type 2 table along a dimension

Tags: sql, type-2-dimension

I have a slowly changing type 2 price change table which I need to reduce the size of to improve performance. Often rows are written to the table even if no price change occurred (when some other dimensional field changed) and the result is that for any product the table could be 3-10x the size it needs to be if it were including only changes in price.

I'd like to compress the table so that it only has contains the first effective date and last expiration date for each price until that price changes that can also

- Deal with an unknown number of rows of the same price
- Deal with products going back to an old price

As an example if i have this raw data:

| Product | Price Effective Date | Price Expiration Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | **6/22/18** | 9/19/18 | 120 |
| 123456 | 9/20/18 | 11/8/18 | 120 |
| 123456 | 11/9/18 | 11/29/18 | 120 |
| 123456 | 11/30/18 | **12/6/18** | 120 |
| 123456 | **12/7/18** | 12/19/18 | 85 |
| 123456 | 12/20/18 | 1/1/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 1/2/19 | **2/19/19** | 85 |
| 123456 | **2/20/19** | **2/20/19** | 120 |
| 123456 | **2/21/19** | 3/19/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 3/20/19 | 5/22/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 5/23/19 | **10/10/19** | 85 |
| 123456 | **10/11/19** | 6/19/19 | 80 |
| 123456 | 6/20/20 | **12/31/99** | 80 |

I need to transform it into this:

| Product | Price Effective Date | Price Expiration Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 6/22/18 | 12/6/18 | 120 |
| 123456 | 12/7/18 | 2/19/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 2/20/19 | 2/20/19 | 120 |
| 123456 | 2/21/19 | 10/10/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 10/11/19 | 12/31/99 | 80 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  I would recommend reconstructing the data, saving it in a temporary table, and then reloading the existing table.

The code to reconstruct the data is:

```
select product, price, min(effective_date), max(expiration_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_expiration_date = effective_date - interval '1 day' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by product order by effective_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(expiration_date) over (partition by product, price order by effective_date) as prev_expiration_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by product, price, grp;
```

Note that the logic for date arithmetic varies depending on the database.

Save this result into a temporary table, `temp_t` or whatever, using `select into`, `create table as`, or whatever your database supports.

Then empty the current table and reload it:

```
truncate table t;

insert into t
    select product, price, effective_date, expiration_date
    from temp_t;
```

Notes:

- Validate the data before using `truncate_table`!
- If there are triggers or columns with default values, you might want to be careful.

Comment: That function to get the grp field is exactly what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the intervals where the price does not change, and then group on those intervals:

```
with to_r as (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) r, t.* from data_table t),
     to_group as (select t.*, (select sum(t1.r < t.r and t1.price != t.price) from to_r t1) c from to_r t)
select t.product, min(t.effective), max(t.expiration), max(t.price) from to_group t group by t.c order by t.r;
```

Output:

| Product | Price Effective Date | Price Expiration Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 6/22/18 | 12/6/18 | 120 |
| 123456 | 12/7/18 | 2/19/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 2/20/19 | 2/20/19 | 120 |
| 123456 | 2/21/19 | 10/10/19 | 85 |
| 123456 | 10/11/19 | 12/31/99 | 80 |

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for a temporal schema? Where for a given date you can know the price of an asset?

This is done with two tables; price_current and price_history.

| price_id | item_id | price | rec_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | '2015-04-18' |

| price_id | item_id | from | to | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2001-01-01' | '2004-05-01' | 114 |
| 1 | 1 | '2004-05-01' | '2015-04-18' | 102 |

i.e. for any item, you can ascertain the date it was set without polluting your "current" table. For this to work effectively you will need to have UPDATE triggers on your current_table. When you update a record you insert into the history table the details and the period it was valid from.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_price_current_update
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO price_history(price_id, item_id, from, to, price)
    SELECT price_id, item_id, rec_created, GETDATE(), price
    FROM rows_updated
END
```

Now you have a distinction between current and historical, without your current table (presumably the busier table) getting out of hand because of maintaining historical state. Hope i understood the question.

To ignore 'dummy' updates, just alter the trigger to ignore empty changes (if that's not handled by the DBMS anyway). Tbh, this should and could be done application side easily enough, but to manage it via the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_price_current_update
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO price_history(price_id, item_id, from, to, price)
    SELECT price_id, item_id, rec_created, GETDATE(), price
    FROM rows_updated u
    INNER JOIN price_current ON u.price_id = p.price_id
    WHERE u.price <> p.price
END
```

i.e. rows_updated contains the record from the update, we insert into the history table the previous row, providing the previous row's price is different from the current row's price.

(edited to include new trigger. I also changed the date held in rec_created, this must be the date the row is created, not the first instance that product had a price assigned to it. that was a mistake. Regarding the dates, I am lazy to put the full DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss:zzz, but that would generally be useful in between queries)

Comment: I don't understand how what you're describing is different from the current table I already have. That has all the price history already and I need to make it smaller. I also can't just get current prices because I need to join it to a historical transactions table to get the selling price at the time of the transaction.

Comment: Different in that a) two tables not one. b) didn't include redundant records c) makes it much simpler to deal with temporal queries, like get selling price at time of transaction

Comment: Rereading my question i should have been clearer, i have the current table and cannot see it's upstream data or edit it. I'm in need of some logic to go from the first to the second, not a redesign of the schema.

Comment: This fails to address my first bullet. This logic would include the range from 12/7 to 2/19 in both the 120 and 85 price with no way to distinguish which is correct.

Comment: see latest answer of mine for this; basically identify every record where if effective -1 there is a different price, or expires + 1 there is a different price. select all of these rows UNION ALL find the row where the effective date is the earliest for that product.

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of:

```
WITH keeps AS
(
SELECT p.product_id, p.effective, p.expires, p.price, CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM prices p1 WHERE p1.effective = DATEADD(DAY, p.exires, 1) AND p1.price <> p.price) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_after, CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM prices p1 WHERE p1.expires = DATEADD(DAY, p.effective, -1) AND p1.price <> p.price) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_before
FROM prices p
)
SELECT * FROM keeps
WHERE has_after = 1
OR has_before = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT p.product_id, p.effective, p.exires, p.price
FROM prices p
WHERE p.effective = (SELECT MIN(effective) FROM prices p1 WHERE p1.product_id = p.product_id)
```

What's it doing:

Find all the entries where there exists another entry whose effective date is that of the previous entry's expiry date + 1, and the price of that new entry is different. This gives us all the actual changes in price. But we miss the first price entry, so we simply include that in the results.

e.g.:

| product_id | effective | expires | price | has_before | has_after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 6/22/18 | 9/19/18 | 120 | 0 | 0 |
| 123456 | 9/20/18 | 11/8/18 | 120 | 0 | 0 |
| 123456 | 11/9/18 | 11/29/18 | 120 | 0 | 0 |
| 123456 | 11/30/18 | 12/6/18 | 120 | 0 | 1 |
| 123456 | 12/7/18 | 12/19/18 | 85 | 1 | 0 |
| 123456 | 12/20/18 | 1/1/19 | 85 | 0 | 0 |
| 123456 | 2/1/19 | 2/19/19 | 85 | 0 | 1 |
| 123456 | 2/20/19 | 2/20/19 | 120 | 1 | 1 |
| 123456 | 2/21/19 | 3/19/19 | 85 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Might be better with querying a subquery rather than the case when exists:

SELECT p.product_id, p.effective, p.expires, p.price, CASE WHEN p1.product_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_key_row
FROM prices p
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT * FROM prices
) p1 ON p.product_id = p1.product_id AND (p1.effective = DATEADD(DAY, p.expires, 1) OR p1.expires = DATEADD(DAY, p.effective, -1))
UNION ALL
SELECT p.product_id, p.effective, p.exires, p.price
FROM prices p
WHERE p.effective = (SELECT MIN(effective) FROM prices p1 WHERE p1.product_id = p.product_id)